# Adding to the TFS 2012 related work items lis

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Does anyone know how to add queries to the list of Related Work Item queries in the TFS pending changes menu?

There are only two in there at the moment, and they are not filtered queries that we use..

Screen show of the area below

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it - It's under the "Work Items" section, and you then add queries to your favourites

[image]